# Detect Object Color Various Lighting OpenCV Java

Tags: java, opencv, embedded

I would like to create a simple openCV application that is able to detect the color red (think red solo cup) accurately in various lighting conditions.

Which would be the best color space to use (RGB,HSV,etc) and how should i go about implementing something like this?

I'm new to use openCV and this would be my first project so any examples would be greatly appreciated.

There are examples out there for detecting but none of them  address how colors can appear different shades and hues based on bright light, shadows, low light, etc and how to compensate for that.

I plan on using this in a embedded project so i could have a photodiode to detect the amount of ambient light, if that information helps...

Thanks!

Comment: There is no sure shot Color Space that would serve your purpose well, But you can start with `HSV` and `YCrCB` color spaces to see which one works better for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a great solution to the problem. I started with this tutorial:

http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/08-object-detection.html

It allows you to move the the HSV values on the fly so you can experiment with different lighting conditions. So, after that I was able to figure out the values that work best for different conditions. Next, I would allow the program to change the hsv values little by little, in hopes of finding the cup, based on my experimenting results.

When the program found an object that it felt good enough about it draws the contour around it.

Edit: By increasing the amount of "blur" i was able to detect the object much more efficiently.

Sorry if i'm using bad terminology. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [this tutorial project](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection/). It detects color using OpenCV in the simplest way possible:

```
# find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
# the mask
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
```

It's Python but that code is straightforward enough to show how it works.

Try this with the pictures your setup is getting first. It's fast and simple for a first attempt.

Detecting red is fairly straightforward until you mess with illumination. At that point, the problem can get REALLY hairy like [the dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress).

So it's best to ignore that problem until you've had a chance to see how it affects your setup. Your illumination constraints may be simple (e.g. bright vs dim pictures) or it could be complex (e.g. blue tinted in the dark, yellow tinted in bright light).